# ChartEvents Column ValueEOM

Tags: mimic-iii

I would Like to know Following information About Chart Events table:

1)full form of the ValueEOM column.

2) what they are used for .

3) Abnormal Values range

For Example:

bpm : Beats per minute

used for : heart rate

Normal Value Range : 60 to 100

There are 100 unique values of the column. It would Be great if some one would help me find these value details. Also if there is any info useful regarding these informtion in MIMIC-iii will also be of great help.

Thanks In Advance.